# css class selector to select text inside a div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a div with a classname "test".  The class "test" has a cursor pointer assigns to it.  The class also has a fixed width of 200px.  Inside the div is text of length that is shorter than the width of the div. I don't want the point to appear when the mouse is placed in the blank part of the div.

Is there a way that I can assign the css pointer to the text inside the div without wrapping the text inside another `<span>` tag.  I just don't want to go back and add the span tag to every single div and rewrite the javascript.

I am thinking of something like this pseudo css code

```
.test.text {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

CSS doesn't work this way. As biziclop says in the comments, [text nodes can't be selected with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-pseudo-selector-for-text-nodes-elements). You'll either have to wrap your text in a `<span>` and use

```
.test span {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

With

```
<div class="test">
    <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Or set `.test` to `display: inline`, but that won't let you give it a width, which is not the behaviour you want. `<span>`s are fine, in this case.

Comment: I don't think making `.test` display inline works here. It has to have the 200-pixel width.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did try to go back and added spans to my texts, but I don't still remember all the different functions that effect the code, so I weighted the benefit of spending time to pretty up the UI vs the cost of spending hours testing for this.  I am still weighing my decision.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements.

I was playing with this solution, for 1-line divs:
http://jsfiddle.net/yAfKw/

Multi-line divs:
http://jsfiddle.net/yAfKw/1/

Works in Firefox, does not work in Safari.

Comment: Thanks biziclop, this is a great trick that could solve my problem, I will test it out.