# Hiding text in an element

Tags: css

Let's say we have:

```
<div id="view-item-hero-info">
    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
    <h4>{{location}}</h4>
    <h3>
        <span id="view-item-hero-header-score">
            You scored {{userScore}}pts
        </span>
    </h3>
    {{description}}
</div>
```

Is there a way I can hide the text directly inside `#view-item-hero-info`? I know I can use `text-indent` but is there another, *nicer*, way?

**Note:** I don't want to hide the element, just everything inside it.

**Note 2:** Hiding all the elements within `#view-item-hero-info` is fine, I can use `#view-item-hero-info > * { display: none }` but then the text directly within `#view-item-hero-info` is still visible. I need `#view-item-hero-info` to remain visible so that its background can be seen but the text inside it must be hidden.

Comment: Which text do you want to hide?

Comment: @BoltClock *people* badger on about not using `text-indent`

Comment: So by "another, *nicer*, way", you simply mean "another way"?

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, another way that's not using `text-indent`

Comment: make the opacity to 0

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
#view-item-hero-info {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: That's probably as close as it's going to get.

Comment: color: transparent; does not work in some browsers.  Some browsers when encountering color: transparent use color:white instead, especially for links.  So I use font-size: 0.1px

Answer (score 2):

Using this CSS:

```
visibility: hidden;
```

hides your element, but preserves the space it would normally take.  Whereas this CSS will hide an element as if it never existed:

```
display: none;
```

Comment: Hmm not quite, I still want the element to be visible, just its children to be hidden

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code if u need hide text

```
.text-hidden{
   font-size: 0;
   text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

to hide all direct child's 
use

```
.hidden-nested > *{
    visibility: hidden; /*or next line */
    display:none ;
}
```

if you need all child's use last code but change class to

```
 .hidden-nested  *
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css display property. In HTML this would look like `<span style="display: none">`

Using javascript: `document.getElementById("view-item-hero-header-score").style.display="none"`

in css:

```
#view-item-hero-header-score {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hmm not quite, I still want the element to be visible, just its children to be hidden

Comment: So stick the text in another span and hide that using visibility: hidden ?

Comment: I can't control if the text is within an element or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you can set a style:

```
visibility:hidden
```

So to hide all descendants (*) within your element:

```
#view-item-hero-info * { visibility: hidden }
```

If instead you only want to hide direct descendants ie children but not grandchildren then you use the direct child selector (>)

Rather than selecting all (*) you can select particular descendants eg divs:

```
#view-item-hero-info div { visibility: hidden }
```

Equally instead of the visibility you can use:

```
display:none
```

The display option doesn't take up space whereas if you want to reserve the space for when the element will be shown you use the visibility option

EDIT:
There isn't a selector just for a text node (ie the text without the element). See [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes-elements). So all children of your span need to be in an element in order to have style applied.

As a hack you could just put another span directly in your main one and all content (including the standalone text) within that. Then the hiding will work.

Comment: Hmm not quite, I still want the element to be visible, just its children to be hidden

Comment: My original answer solved your original question (hiding the span). I've updated it now that you want to hide the children/descendants

Comment: Again, I think I haven't explained this correctly, please see the edit.

Comment: I'm not able to add or remove elements, I can only work with that HTML. Oh well, it seems `text-indent` is the only answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use JS to iterate though all child items in the elements DOM and then use JS to overwrite the CSS? Something like:

```
var items_i_want = document.getElementById("view-item-hero-header-score").elements

for(var i = 0; i < items_i_want .length; i++)
{
    items_i_want [i].style.display="none"
}
```