# CSS selector for tag contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I've tried finding a similar question to this so please forgive me if it's been asked before.

I am trying to create a CSS selector for the contents that appear between the open and closed tags (rather than element content)

For example,

```
<span class="title">4</span>
```

I want to be able to target any span tag that has the number 4 in it (the 4 being the only number there..  not 14 or 44 or anything like that.)

I have even tried the following css...

```
span[*="4"] {
    // do something
    }
```

but obviously I am just stabbing at things here.  I know how to select an element's content but I just want to match that which is in between the open and closed tag.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think there is a selector for that....

Comment: No, there is no pure CSS selector to select based on content. At max, you could select based on attributes only.

Comment: As far as I know there's no stream reading through the open and closed tags...

Comment: Your answers is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645552/is-it-possible-to-use-an-input-value-attribute-as-a-css-selector

Comment: can it be done with javascript?

Comment: @Neophyte Polyhistor: "Stream"? That sounds an awful lot like an irrelevant implementation detail to me.

Comment: No pure CSS selector for that. If you need to do that dynamically, adding a class with jQuery or just JS based on the content should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Boltclock well, what's the best way to phrase it ?

Comment: I guess Im at a loss.  Turen... I don't see how that link helps either but thanks.