# Dealing with :invalid pseudo class on not empty mail inputs pure CSS

Tags: css, validation, input

I want to create some modern forms with animated labels working as placeholders first and bars by using CSS transitions.

```
/* USED STYLING */
input:focus ~ label,
input:valid ~ label,
input:invalid {
    top: -15px;
    color: #00bfff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input:focus ~ span,
input:valid ~ span {
    width: 100%;
}

/* VALID/INVALID STYLING */
input:valid ~ label {
    color: #01df01;
}
input:valid ~ span {
    background-color: #01df01;
}

/* set invalid (not empty) styling here */
```

[here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PatrickVIVID/uo0kycys/30/)

As you can see, it works pretty good except the mail input.

Is there any way right now to deal with the valid/invalid state on not empty mail inputs by using pure CSS?

I know the one and most used option is to set the type of the mail input to text too and doing the validation check with js or jQuery. I usually do it the same way but there is a point which bothers me as a mobile user (iOS) for a long time. The keyboard change. Well not really the change itself but the point that, if the input is text, the autocorrect's setting for the first letter to be uppercase.

Ok maybe I'm a little fussy with this but the thing is putting a mail address in a text input isn't correctly in the semantic of modern html isn't it?

Thanks and regards 
Patrick

Comment: "deal" with it how? It's not clear what you are asking. Have you considered using a pattern?

Comment: In my example the label moves on top of the input while focusing and stays there if the typed value is valid. Works with text, password and more inputs, because there the the state turns valid if there is content. At mail or url inputs the the content is only valid if there is a correct syntax in it. So if a user types in any incorrect address the state isn't valid anymore and when the user stops focusing the input the label falls back back down. Now I'm thinking about if there's any way to place the label still on top whether the typed content is valid or not but only if there is content.

Comment: It would seem you can not target dynamic values with css

http://stackoverflow.com/a/10645583/1143411

Comment: Your link is broken