# querySelectorAll to get input sliders with a specific name and also value

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

How do I get querySelectorAll to return all sliders with name="type" and also value="0"

My current code looks like this:

```js
function getSlider0Values(name) {
    const sliders = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name = "${name}"][value='0'] `);
    let type_0preference_list = [];
    sliders.forEach((range) => {
        type_0preference_list.push(range.id);
    });
    return type_0preference_list;
}
```

```html
<div class="type_sliders">
  <label for="Apples">Apples</label>
  <input type="range" name="type" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="Apples" class="type_slider">

  <label for="Peaches">Peaches</label>
  <input type="range" name="type" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="Peaches" class="type_slider">

  <label for="Pears">Pears</label>
  <input type="range" name="type" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="Pears" class="type_slider">
</div>
```

It's currently selecting all sliders, not just the ones with the value 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a bit confusing, because while range.value will give you the current value of the slider the test for value='0' in CSS does not get updated on input changing.

You can update the attribute on a change and then your selecting will work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645552/is-it-possible-to-use-an-input-value-attribute-as-a-css-selector) for a bit more explanation.

One thing you can do is listen for the change event on each input and update the actual attribute accordingly. Alternatively you could just do that in your function and not bother with additional event listeners. It depends on your actual use case.

This snippet does an update on a change by setting an event listener on each input so the value attribute is always uptodate.

```js
//set an event listener on each input so value attribute can be updated
const allSliders = document.querySelectorAll('input.type_slider');
allSliders.forEach((slider) => {
  slider.addEventListener('change', function() {
    slider.setAttribute('value', slider.value);
  });
});

function getSlider0Values(name) {
    const sliders = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name = "${name}"][value='0'] `);
    let type_0preference_list = [];
    sliders.forEach((range) => {
        type_0preference_list.push(range.id);
    });
    return type_0preference_list;
}
```

```html
<div class="type_sliders">
  <label for="Apples">Apples</label>
  <input type="range" name="type" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="Apples" class="type_slider">

  <label for="Peaches">Peaches</label>
  <input type="range" name="type" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="Peaches" class="type_slider">

  <label for="Pears">Pears</label>
  <input type="range" name="type" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="Pears" class="type_slider">
</div>
<button onclick="console.log(getSlider0Values('type'))">Alter some slider(s) and then click me</button>
```

Comment: Awesome, it finally works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. You are getting all the sliders because all of theme have `name="type"` and `value="0"`.

```js
const inputs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT'));

const handler = (e) => {
    const result = inputs.filter((input) => {
        return (input.value === '0' && input.name === 'type');
    });
    
    console.log(result);
};

document.getElementById('Container').addEventListener('change', handler)
```

```html
<div id="Container" class="type_sliders">
  <label for="Apples">Apples</label>
  <input type="range" name="type" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="Apples" class="type_slider">

  <label for="Peaches">Peaches</label>
  <input type="range" name="type" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="Peaches" class="type_slider">

  <label for="Pears">Pears</label>
  <input type="range" name="type" min="0" max="5" value="0" id="Pears" class="type_slider">
</div>
```

Comment: At the start, yes, but even when I change the slider's position, the result is still the same. Is there some other way I should be getting its actual value (it's "dot" position)?

Comment: @nikolask.design I didn't understand the question. I've just updated my answer accordingly. There is no need to add one event listener per input and there is no need to "update" the "value" attribute of the inputs.