# How to remove the text from this html

Tags: html, css, drupal

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
<h2 class="element-invisible">You are here</h2>
<a href="/cashback/">Home</a> 
admin
</div>
```

Can any one suggest how to remove the "admin" from the above html by using css?  I can't modify the html directly.

Comment: the only way to achieve this is to have a css selector that selects only text node, and apply `display:none` to it. Unfortunately, there isn't, so your question is unanswerable using css alone :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes-elements

Comment: Can you use javascript? can you put a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` part?

Comment: take a look, using javascript http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/03/07/how-to-find-and-replace-text-dynamically-via-javascript/

Comment: Thank you all:):) I never thought i would such a support from u all. Wesley's solution provided the trick in my case. Once again thanks a lot buddies:):)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do this with just CSS:

```
.breadcrumb {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.breadcrumb * {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you. Don't forget to accept an answer to close the question :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `str_replace('admin','',$var_name);` if you have variable of this html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`<span style="display:none;">admin</span>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer kapil. These codes are from Drupal. I cannot customise them. So is there any other means by which i can hide them?

Answer (score 0):

Try using position relative with a negative left position, I don't know if you can apply those styles with no problem in your Drupal site, but at least it works in the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/cadence96/M5pfV/1/

First give a relative position to the container moving it away of the view applying a css style of left: -9999px
then select the children elements, give them position relative, and style them with left: 9999px, this way you'll get your necessary elements back in the view.

PD: I tried to use the same process with negative text indent, but I don't know why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
text-indent:-9999px;
position:relative;
```

for IE7:

```
text-transform:uppercase;
```