# How to get element's text without retrieving the text from its descendant

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="t-beaneditor-row">
    <label>Login ID</label>
    SeleniumReset
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the string "SeleniumReset" from the HTML using WebDriver Java. I have tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div")).getText()
```

but it is giving me "Login ID SeleniumReset". How to I retrieve "SeleniumReset" only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt if this is possible in Selenium WebDriver.

Similar posts here:

- [Getting text from a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505375/getting-text-from-a-node)
- [Reading text using selenium webdriver(xpath)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811066/)

So in your case, something like (untested pseudo Java code):

```
String divText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div")).getText();
String labelText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/label")).getText();
divText.replace(labelText, "").trim();
```

Comment: +1, and as for the problem itself, well, if you get the element's text in JS directly, you'll see the same issue: `document.getElementsByClassName("t-beaneditor-row")[0].innerText;` ....thus this is not a Selenium issue (directly, anyway).