# Hide anything not in a paragraph using CSS or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I am looking to hide anything not in a `<p>` within a certain `<div>` - specifically anything before the first `<p>`. For example:

```
<div id="description">
TEXT I WANT REMOVED
<p>Keep this text</p>
<p>Keep this too</p>
</div>
```

Comment: use `div{
visibility:hidden;
}
div p{
visibility:visible;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there [isn't something like a text-node-selector in css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5688712/288773), so the only thing that comes to my mind to solve this is setting `font-size: 0;` for the outer element and back to a normal value for the `p`s (although this feels kind of... dirty).

[see it in action on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MvXBu/)

Comment: It works well - but like you said, its not clean to have to reset the font-size on the inner element.

Comment: still better than using javascript (wich seems to be the only usefil alternative), in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use visibility - but the problem is the space occupied by the other elements may not be properly collapsed

```
#description {
    visibility: collapse;
}
#description p{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vrdXc/)

Another solution is

```
$('#description').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) != '';
}).wrap('<span />').parent().hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v5bfZ/)

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try jquery:

```
var html = $('#description p').map(function(){
    return $(this)[0].outerHTML;
}).get();

$('#description').html(html);
```

[Demo Fiddle to try](http://jsfiddle.net/6eHQm/1/)