# css - style everything that comes before or after a specific tag

Tags: css

I would like to style everything that comes after `<br/>` ("Suite B102") in this string:

```
<li><a href="#/bnj">BNJ Travel <br/>Suite B102</a>
</li>
```

Is this possible with only css?

EDIT: without using span

Comment: "*EDIT: without using span*" or other inline element? No. [CSS can't apply styles to text nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5688712). You'll need to add an element around the snippet of text and apply the styles to that element.

Comment: CSS can't do that. If you want to apply a specific style to certain text, then that text should be it's own node, and must be put inside another element.

Comment: Impossible with only CSS .

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a `<span>`, and then apply CSS to the span.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
.yourStyle{
  ...
}
```

html:

```
<li>
  <a href="#/bnj">BNJ Travel <br/><span class = "yourStyle">Suite B102</span></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to define what occurs after anchor tag, either with a `div` or `span` depending on what you are trying to alter.

Alternatively, you could apply a style to the `li` and negate that style in the anchored link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#/bnj">BNJ Travel <br/>Suite B102</a>
</li>
```

change this to

```
<li><a href="#/bnj">BNJ Travel <br/><span class="aspan">Suite B102<span></a>
</li>
```

Now in your css

use the class to style the section for example

```
.aspan{
color: red;
}
```