# CSS: first-child selector including text nodes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

is there any way to select a CSS-element that is the first child of its parent, *counting text nodes*? I want to remove the top margin of a heading if it is at the top of its parent, but if I use:

```
#content h1 {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
#content h1:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

and have some HTML like

```
<div id="content">
    This is some text.
    <h1>A heading</h1>
    Some more text.
</div>
```

the margin is still removed. Is there any way in CSS to prevent this?

Comment: You can't select text nodes with CSS. You'd need to change your markup. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5688758/1612146

Comment: alright, thanks. The markup is created by the showdown markdown parser, but I will take a look at it, thanks :-) I thought if there was any way in using `:before:empty` or something like that, but I think CSS can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `margin`, not just the `margin-top`, h1 element is pushing the next element down

```
#content h1 {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
#content h1:first-child {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6TA8N/1/)

If you want to remove all except first

```
#content h1:not(:first-child) {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38kJK/2/)

Comment: the problem is that actually, I WANT the margin for the first heading of your example, because there is a text node before it.

Comment: @BlackWolf i have updated the answer, now it removes the margin except from first heading

Comment: Thanks for the effort... its a good trick, unfortunately still not what I need, since I would need the margin to be removed from the first child if it appears before any text. So in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmgB7/) the margin of the first heading should be 0. I think oGeez was right in saying CSS cannot do this, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In the example given in the OP, you could (remove the `:first-child` rule and) add

```
#content {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

This would [collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) (combine and overlap) with the `h1`’s margin if there’s no text before the heading, but if there is the `h1` would have a separate top margin.  You’d then just have to adjust the bottom padding/margin of whatever is preceding so that your `#content` is positioned desirably, or perhaps alternatively add a `::before` pseudo-element with a negative margin (which will collapse with and cancel out the container’s margin) to do the trick:

```
#content:before {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  content: ' ';
}
```

Note that if `h1` has a different `font-size` then `1em` will different so you would have to account for that or use a fixed unit such as `rem` or `px`.

(This doesn’t help in my case – I want to add a top-margin to a `float`ed `img` if there’s some text before it in the containing `<p>` [in WordPress-generated content].  But margins of `float`-ed elements don’t collapse with their container, and the general answer to the question is “no, there’s no such selector.”)