# CSS conditional margin with (CSS only, no JS)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

## Problem Description

I have this (quite common) problem. If I float an image, I can give margins to it so it wraps around the image with some space. So, if I do this:

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<img class="alignleft" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
<p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. <strong>Lor separat existentie es un myth.</strong> Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.
  <em>Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca:</em> On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu commun paroles.</p>
<p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. <strong>Lor separat existentie es un myth.</strong> Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.
  <em>Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca:</em> On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu commun paroles.</p>
```

And it works fine, of course.... as long as the image is at the top of the element. But if I add it in the middle of the text, this is what will happen:

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. <strong>Lor separat existentie es un myth.</strong> Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.
  <img class="alignleft" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" /> <em>Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca:</em> On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation
  e plu commun paroles.</p>

<p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. <strong>Lor separat existentie es un myth.</strong> Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.
  <em>Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca:</em> On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu commun paroles.</p>
```

just in case, here's the issue:

[image]

Since it has `margin:0`, the image has no space above. Obviously, I could add `margin:15px` and be a happy camper, but then I'd have a 15px space above the image when it is the first element.

I tried using `.alignleft:not(:first-line)` but it didn't work, not even adding the image inside the `p` tag, so I'm out of ideas

## The Question

So, basically, my question is: is it possible to make these margins behave in a conditional way?

Comment: According to your code example, only the images within paragraphs, e.g. `p > img`, need top/right/bottom padding, while the other images just need right/bottom. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wadcro28/ . Or am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for the first child, taking text nodes into account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074295/is-there-a-css-selector-for-the-first-child-taking-text-nodes-into-account)

Comment: If it has to do with screen size look at css media stements. You could try ajusting line height. You could also use a class for img insde p element and another one fore img that are not inside the p element.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister, how is this a duplicate? The other question is about inserting content in the middle of tags, (which I think is impossible and doesn't have an accepted answer). These are properly closed tags and there's no insertion in the middle whatsoever, kind of the exact opposite to that question

Comment: @MadeInDreams, no, it's not related to screen sizes. The class part is possible, of course, but not really suitable. This is for a WP site and final users aren't computer savvy, so asking them to add a class is kind of a no go

Comment: `.alignleft { margin-top: 0; } p .alignleft { margin-top: 15px; }`

Comment: @connexo: while I made a mistake in my code (image shouldn't be inside of the p tag) WordPress tends to include images inside P tags, so this could work on quite some cases, thank you! :)

Comment: @Devin This is my reasoning for it being a duplicate, and I may well be mistaken: You are trying to style an element (the image) based on whether a text node comes before it or it is the true first child. I am distinguishing this from the case in your question where the image is outside the `p` element, because otherwise you could just use a `p > img` selector to distinguish whether it's before a paragraph or inside a paragraph. If my possible duplicate was not valid, I expected you to comment and voters to read that before dupe voting, so no worries.

Comment: How should the image display if it's inside the `p`, but before all its text? Should it be different from the case when it's before `p`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your HTML, apply the `margin-top: 15px` only when the `img` is a child (or following sibling) of the `p`.

```css
.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 15px 15px 0;
}

p > .alignleft {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

/* if the img is a following sibling, try this:

  p ~ .alignleft { margin-top: 15px }

*/
```

```html
<img class="alignleft" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />
<p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. <strong>Lor separat existentie es un myth.</strong> Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.
  <em>Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca:</em> On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu commun paroles.</p>
<p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. <strong>Lor separat existentie es un myth.</strong> Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.
  <em>Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca:</em> On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu commun paroles.</p>


<hr>
<p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. <strong>Lor separat existentie es un myth.</strong> Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.
  <img class="alignleft" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" /> <em>Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca:</em> On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation
  e plu commun paroles.</p>

<p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. <strong>Lor separat existentie es un myth.</strong> Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.
  <em>Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca:</em> On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu commun paroles.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way!

```css
p img {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}

img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}
```

```html
<p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. <strong>Lor separat existentie es un myth.</strong> Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.
  <img class="alignleft" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" /> <em>Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca:</em> On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation
  e plu commun paroles.</p>

<p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. <strong>Lor separat existentie es un myth.</strong> Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.
  <em>Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca:</em> On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu commun paroles.</p>
```