# Is there a way to have a specific content based CSS for e.g. numbers

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to put a check in SASS files or CSS files to check for the content inside a div:

For e.g.: If a div has numbers in it I want the content inside it to be aligned to the right and whereas if the div has text in it I want the content to be aligned to the left.

Is it possible. I see it happening on a lot of websites, and I pretty sure that they must not have hard-coded it that way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a CSS selector for text nodes/elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no. thats not possible. you need to check it somewhere else.

you could for example check the content in php code and then depending on the type of content add a css-class to the parent html-element.

Comment: The store returns so much data, I didn't want to put a check on each and every record in JavaScript.

Comment: @kapilchhattani what kind of CMS?

Comment: you‘ll have to find the place in the shop’s code where the markup is generated. i can‘t imagine another good way to do this.

Comment: ? Didnt get you... Can you elaborate a bit.

Comment: website basics: there is a browser, that understands html, css and js. and there is a database in the back. and in between, there is a layer that generates the html (markup) with the content from the database. thats where you need to digg in, in order to add a content-related css-class to the html. 

PS: mark my answer as correct if you didn't find a way to style your content by only touching your sass/css files.

Comment: I guess no one has figured out a way to do this.