# element inside td tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello StackOverFlow</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hi! I am new to html, can someone tell me what type of element is the word 'Hello StackOverFlow' inside the **td tag**? Is it a label?

Comment: It is a text node.

Comment: What he said. However, if you're referring to the `<td>` then that is a *table data* (I usually refer to it as a *cell*) .

Comment: it refers to table data (td)

Comment: So how should I address it  for styling? table tr td textnode?

Comment: For styling with CSS: `td { background-color: #000; }`, unless you need something more specific

Comment: @EthylCasin are you referring to the selector?

Comment: How to style the textnode inside the td tag?

Comment: If you want to change the textnode *within* a `td` then all the manipulations are done with the parent `td`. For example: `td { font-size: 2 em; }`

Comment: I don't understand why people are using css when css tag has not even been added to the question. You simply need to check for it's **nodeType** .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element inside the `<td>` tag is a text node. You can't address it in CSS. If you want to style it, you either have to style the `<td>` tag or surround the text you want to style with a `<span>` element.

So to, e.g., style only the `Hello`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Hello<span> StackOverFlow</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And in your CSS

```
span { font-weight: bold; }
```

Or whatever style you want to give it.

See also the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688758/1396068).

Answer (score 3):

Want to check the type of *Hello Stackoverflow*? Simpy check the td's content's `nodeType`

```
//Gave your td an id of 'td'
alert($('#td').contents().get(0).nodeType);
```

This will return 3. A nodeType of 3 means it is a text.

Here is an image of each nodeType:

[image: w3schools image on nodeType]

[w3schools on nodeType](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp)