# Css - Select text inside element inside element, without whats in the outside div

Tags: css, html

I have a html div:

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <a>Title</a>
    (0)
</li>
```

I want to hide the "(0)" And leave the title.

I tried something like

**CSS**

```
li { display:none }
li a {display:block }
```

doesn't show the text inside the a tag after hides it.

How could I hide only what it is inside the div and not inside the a tag?

Comment: why dont you use another tag to wrap that free text?

Comment: I got access only to style.css in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
   li{
     visibility:collapse;
    }
    li a {
        visibility:visible;
    }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/33xvuxu6/1/)**

Comment: It works. The problem is that the li lost its list style. If i add display:list-item; to li a, the bullet becomes part of the link and its not what i want. How could i show the the list style with the code above?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to hide i'll use this.

```
li { font-size:0px }
li a {font-size: 20px }
```

Maybe in other case you can use a span inside li tag

```
   <li>
     <a>Title</a>
       <span>(0)</span>
   </li>
```

And Style

```
    li span{ display:none }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly target text nodes with CSS as discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes).  You can, however, achieve what you want with jquery or straight javascript.

```js
 $('li').contents().each(function () {
     if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) $(this).remove();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Title</a>
        (0)
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

No you can't. All child elements will be hidden if you hide it's parent element.