# Converting XPath to CSS Selector

Tags: java, xpath, css-selectors, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to scrape a page for data but the data is not in a specific tag.

`<strong>LABEL IS HERE</strong> DATA IS HERE`

Using an XPath I am able to get a path `//*[@id="center-text"]/text()[1]` but unfortunately chrome does not allow me to copy the CSS Path.

I can get a CSS Path for the `<strong> LABEL IS HERE</strong>` but not for the other text. Is there a way to get this data using CSS Selector language?

---

Sample data

```
<div id="center-text"> 
      <strong>ifno</strong> data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong>ifno</strong> data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong>Tifno</strong> data
      <br> 
      <strong>ifno</strong> data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong>ifno</strong> data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong>ifno</strong> data 
</div>
```

Comment: Is that line wrapped from another tag?

Comment: @VoodooCoder take a look at my edit that is the div where the data is comming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSOUP you can use [nextSibling](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#nextSibling--) method:

> **public Node nextSibling()**
>
> Get this node's next sibling.
>
> **Returns:**
>       next sibling, or null if this is the last sibling

You should get out by:

```
Elements elements = doc.select("div[id=\"center-text\"] strong");

for(Element element : elements) {
    System.out.println("nextSibling: " + element.nextSibling());
}
```

The result will be:

```
nextSibling:  data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
nextSibling:  data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
nextSibling:  data
nextSibling:  data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
nextSibling:  data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
nextSibling:  data
```

Comment: This answer is correct but i did have to change your XPath to css. It should be `#center-text`. But otherwise it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: The general problem underlying this is that you can't select a Text-Node with CSS selectors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes