# Differentiate element from inline text

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'd like have a margin on an element, on the right if the element is the first element of the parent `<div>`, or on the left if the element is the last element of the parent `<div>`.

The thing is, there is no other element in the `<div>`, only plain text.

Here's where I am:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <i>&rarr;</i>Action
</div>

<div class="parent">
    Action<i>&larr;</i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent i:first-child {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.parent i:last-child {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

With the first selector I'm trying to target the first `<div>`, and with the last selector I'm trying to target the last `<div>`.

But actually since `<i>` is the only child element, both rules apply to this element.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbhtffbv/).

Is there a way I can select the `<i>` that is at the beginning or the end of the parent, without modifying the markup? (Adding a `<span>` to wrap the text is not the solution I'm looking for...)

Comment: CSS doesn't select text nodes so I don't think you will be able to achieve this without wrapping the text in another tag.

Comment: That's what I wanted to find out... I think I'll need to change the markup then...

Comment: Although you could control the text using `content` on the `:before` or `:after` pseudo selectors.

Comment: True, but not the solution I am looking for either... I guess I'll just go with the `<span>` wrapping.

Comment: @JordanBecker Is there something in particular you are trying to achieve? Perhaps there is an "out of the box" way to get the result without modifying the markup.

Comment: I'm trying to add a margin to separate the `<i>` tag from the text. So if the `<i>` tag is placed before the text, I want it to have a margin to the right only. Likewise when the `<i>` tag is after the text, I want it to only have a left margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes), and on the comments on my original question here, it seems that there is no way to achieve text node selection in CSS.

Therefore to address my issue I have to wrap my text node in an inline element, like `<span>`, in order for my `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors to work as expected.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbhtffbv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="parent">
     <i>&rarr;</i>Action
</div>

<div class="parent">
    Action<i>&larr;</i>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>


.parent {
    float: left;
}
.parent:first-child {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```