# Select text within a div using CSS Attribute

Tags: css

Trying to select a certain block of text within a div using CSS attribute.

Doesn't seem to be taking, any other options? I have tried variences of

```
 .welcome [text~="You are logged in as"]{
    display:none;
 }
```

The HTML text is

```
 <div id="welcome">
    You are logged in as <a href="example.com">Me</a> <b>(</b> <a   href="http://example.com/index.php?route=account/logout">Logout</a> <b>)</b>         </div>
```

Comment: You are using the _attribute_ selector for _contents_. I dont think its possible to do what you want, and if it is, it is certainly not advised (what if someone corrects the wording only slightly? Or you want a slightly different message? Try to keep your CSS as separate from your content as possible so you don't need to change both when you want to change only one).

Comment: you cannot select using css please refer this for futher description
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes

Answer (score 4):

You can use `[ ]` only for html attributes (like id, class...), not for text. You have to use javascript or something else for this.
Btw, it's `#welcome`, not `.welcome` :)

Answer (score 1):

You could alter the html slightly, to target the whole text or parts of it:

```
<div id="welcome">
  <span class="target_one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
  <span class="target_two">Aenean quis augue gravida, ornare arcu quis, gravida arcu.</span>
</div>
```

Then the css becomes easy enough:

```
#welcome .target_one { color:red; }
#welcome .target_two { color:green; }
```