# Targeting text nodes with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm working on the CSS for a container object. I have it mostly working. Specifically, I'm looking at test case 1, 2 and 3. They all have text nodes. Is there a way to treat a text node just like any child element?

Is there any way to tweak the CSS to get text nodes and its siblings to work nicely? Barring that is there a CSS selector to use that will select a `.container` if any only if there is a text node so I can `display: none` it (or something nicer but still to let the dev know things aren't working)?

Here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqQQrN) as well.

```css
code,
p,
quote {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
code {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
p {
  background-color: #0df;
}
quote {
  background-color: #fd0;
}
quote::after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.third {
  height: 100%;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.container >:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}
.container >:last-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}
.container >:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
.container >:only-child {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 0;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<p>p</p>
<br />
<code>code</code>
<br />
<quote>quote</quote>

<div id="0" class="container">
  text
</div>

<div id="1" class="container">
  <p>first child</p>
  text
  <code>last child</code>
</div>

<div id="2" class="container">
  <p>first child</p>
  text
</div>

<div id="3" class="container">
  text
  <p>last child</p>
</div>

<div id="4" class="container">
  <p>first child</p>
  <code>last child</code>
</div>

<div id="5" class="container">
  <code>first child</code>
  <p>last child</p>
</div>

<div id="6" class="container">
  <code>first child</code>
  <code>last child</code>
</div>

<div id="7" class="container">
  <p>first child</p>
  <p>last child</p>
</div>

<div id="8" class="container">
  <code>only child</code>
</div>

<div id="9" class="container">
  <p>first child</p>
  <quote>middle child</quote>
  <quote>middle child</quote>
  <p>last child</p>
</div>

<div id="10" class="container">
  <quote>
    <div class="third">1</div>
    <div class="third">2</div>
    <div class="third">3</div>
  </quote>
</div>

<div id="11" class="container">
  <quote class="hidden">hidden child</quote>
  <p>first child</p>
  <p>last child</p>
</div>

<div id="12" class="container">
  <p>first child</p>
  <p>last child</p>
  <quote class="hidden">hidden child</quote>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449496/dealing-with-invisible-children-in-css

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes)

Answer (score 6):

Only text that is wrapped in HTML tags can be targeted by CSS.

Your text that is not explicitly wrapped by HTML tags is algorithmically wrapped by *anonymous boxes*. These boxes may inherit styles, but they cannot be targeted by CSS.

From the spec:

> [**9.2.1.1 Anonymous block
>   boxes**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level)
>
> The properties of anonymous boxes are inherited from the enclosing
>   non-anonymous box. Non-inherited properties have their initial value.

If adding HTML tags around your anonymous text is not an option, consider setting the text styles on the container. For the elements that can be targeted, you can then override the container styles. Of course, this method will fall flat if you want the text to have `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd be tempted to place each text node inside a `<span>` which is the classic, non-semantic phrasing element.

*(**See:** http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/span.html)*

You can then style the `span` in a similar manner to the way you have styled the `p` and the `code`.

If you choose this approach, you have two choices. You can either:

1) Write the `spans` directly into the markup:

```css
code, p, quote, span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {background-color: #0df;}
code {background-color: #ccc;}
span {background-color: #fff;}


.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.container :first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}
.container >:last-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}
.container >:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
.container >:only-child {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 0;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-1" class="container">
<p>first child</p>
<span>text</span>
<code>last child</code>
</div>

<div id="container-2" class="container">
  <p>first child</p>
  <span>text</span>
</div>

<div id="container-3" class="container">
  <span>text</span>
  <p>last child</p>
</div>
```

Or, if you prefer not to have `spans` included in your markup, you can

2) Add the `span` elements dynamically, after the page loads:

```js
var containers = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < containers[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
        if (containers[i].childNodes[j].nodeName !== '#text') {continue;} /* skips all nodes which aren't text nodes */
        if (/^[\s\n]*$/.test(containers[i].childNodes[j].textContent)) {continue;} /* skips all text nodes containing only whitespace and newlines */

        var text = containers[i].childNodes[j];
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.appendChild(text);
        span.textContent = span.textContent.trim();
        containers[i].insertBefore(span,containers[i].childNodes[j]);
    }
}
```

```css
code, p, quote, span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {background-color: #0df;}
code {background-color: #ccc;}
span {background-color: #fff;}


.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.container :first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}
.container >:last-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}
.container >:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  border-right-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
.container >:only-child {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 0;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
  margin-left: -0.5rem;
  margin-right: -0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-1" class="container">
<p>first child</p>
text
<code>last child</code>
</div>

<div id="container-2" class="container">
<p>first child</p>
text
</div>

<div id="container-3" class="container">
text
<p>last child</p>
</div>
```