# How to select the third line of text in one div with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to select the third line of text in one div with CSS?

```
<div>
...first...
...second...
...third...
</div>
```

Comment: [It can only be done if the lines of text are wrapped in elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38449462/3597276)

Comment: select to do what?

Comment: And made it green for example.

Comment: Has the text any separation of any kind, e.g. a `<br>`, or it is simply a text that self wrap into 3 lines?

Comment: here is an idea if you want to color : https://jsfiddle.net/h1p2j4s9/