# CSS selector: Is there a way to select every descendent except the first element?

Tags: css, testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, testcafe

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="passage">
  <header>a bunch of stuff and elements here</header>
  text
  <div/>
  text
</div>
```

is there a CSS selector that will allow me to select everything in passage, excluding the header? In this example, it would give me this:

```
  text
  <div/>
  text
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49609442/8620333

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38449462/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a class to your header
e.g.:

```
<header class="header">a bunch of stuff and elements here</header>
```

And then try to select all elements in passage which don't have class .header:

```
.passage *:not(.header) {...}
```