# Don't show a tag inside of another tag in jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

**The HTML**

```
<td> SCH4UE-01 : Chemistry <br> Block: 1 - rm. 315 </br></td>
```

I **don't** want the `br` tag, but I **do** want all of the other text (`SCH4UE-01 : Chemistry`)

**CSS queries I have tried**

`td:eq(0)` outputs: `SCH4UE-01 : Chemistry Block: 1 - rm. 315`

**however**

`br` outputs: `Block: 1 - rm. 315`

Comment: The `td` tag should be inside a `table`. Please add the full HTML so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `<br>` tag is an empty tag which means that it has no end tag.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Replacing your `</br>` tag with `<br>` (if you print the jsoup document you will see, that jsoup fixes such mistakes automatically) your `<td>`tag has four childnodes:

- `#text`
- `br`
- `#text`
- `br`

So the text `SCH4UE-01 : Chemistry` is the first childnode (`element.childNode(0)`).

**Code**

```
String htmlString = "<html><body><table><td> SCH4UE-01 : Chemistry <br> Block: 1 - rm. 315 <br></td></table></body></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

Elements tdElements = doc.select("td");

for (Element tdElement : tdElements){
    System.out.println(tdElement.childNode(0));
}
```

**Output**

```
 SCH4UE-01 : Chemistry
```

Comment: This works but why doesn't the CSS query work? Isn't `eq:(0)` equivalent to `childNode(0)`?

Comment: `:eq(index)`: :eq(n): "find elements whose sibling index is equal to n;". So it finds other tds with same sibling index. Also: TextNodes aren't html elements, so `tdElement.children().size()` is 2 (only the two `<br>` tags). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes