# Css :not is not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, selector

As I would expect, the background of the text `"Color Blue"` should be colored blue and not the `"No color"`. However, none of them are colored.

```html
    <html>
    <style>
    #main > :not(a)  {
        background: blue;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="main">
        Color Blue     
        <br>
        <a>No color</a>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can I color the bg of the text "Color blue" in blue **without changing** the html code?
Here is the expected output as requested:

[image]

Comment: To confirm: are you trying to apply background styling to just the "Color Blue" text. Would applying a background style to the whole div, and then setting the background on "no color" to be another color work?

Comment: yes indeed. And I don't want to change the html code if possible. Just the text "color blue"

Comment: What do you want the final output to look like? Does it not work to have a blue background on eveything in #main, except for the link?

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS selector `#main > :not(a)` says match "any elements that are a direct child of #main, except for a elements".

Unfortunately, "Color Blue" is not in a child element, so your CSS selector doesn't match it. Equally unfortunate - you can't directly target text nodes (see: [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes)), so you can't just style the "Color Blue" text

Instead, perhaps you can style the whole of #main, but then change the background color of the a to be something else? e.g.

```
#main { background: blue; }
#main > a { background: white; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? Please let me know :)

Here is your output:

[image: img]

```css
a {
  background: white;
}
 :not(a) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    Color Blue
    <br>
    <a>No color</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no styles for text-nodes
You might consider making a tag to appear in a different line using inline-block/block

check the following snippet

```css
#main a{
  display:block;
}
#main *:not(a){
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
        <span>Color Blue  </span>  
      
        <a>No color</a>
      </div>
```

Hope this helps