# Bullet-like list without list

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following html-Code

```
<div class="magicbullets">
Nice
awesome
cool
</div>
```

I need it to behave like

```
<div class="magicbullets">
<ul>
<li>nice</li>
<li>aweseome</li>
<li>cool</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I could wrap the `<ul></ul>` around the content, but I cannot modify the content itself by line (nice,awesome,cool). I only have to option to use CSS to achieve what I want.

I managed to create the required new-Line

```
.magicbullets {
     white-space: pre-line;
}
```

for each entry, but `list-style-type` does not really work without a list.

To sum up This is what it should look like:

- nice
- awesome
- cool

Is this doable using **pure CSS** or is some kind of clientcode(JS, jQuery) or servercode(PHP) needed?

Comment: Are you open to using PHP? You could write a function that converts line breaks into LIs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes)

Comment: (Aka. No, not possible with your current markup without JS or PHP.)

Comment: @Serlite Definitely possible with CSS alone, just very tedious...

Comment: The best I can think of is something along the lines of `.magicbullets:nth-child(n+1)::before`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS background property to generate a pattern and then position it where you need.

```css
.magicbullets {
    white-space: pre-line;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1em;
} 

.magicbullets::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 30px;
  top: 16px;
  left: -32px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, black 10%, transparent 10%), 8px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="magicbullets">
Nice
awesome
cool
</div>
```

You can play around with the numbers to get the bullets as you'd like.

Comment: May I ask what is the element that produces 3 bullets ?

Comment: @Apostolos Hi, it's a pseudoelement with a pattern of repeating dots, positioned to line up with the text.

Answer (score 2):

One more CSS solution (but I would really go with JavaScript/jQuery):

```css
.magicbullets {
     white-space: pre-line;
     position:relative;
       overflow:hidden;
       padding-left:13px;
} 
.magicbullets:before {
 content: " ";
 background-image:url('https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/120114-200.png');
  position: absolute;
    left:-5px;
    top:20px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-size:10% 10%;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="magicbullets">
Nice
awesome
cool
</div>
```

So, find good transparent dot/bullet(s) .png, and play with it and `:before` pseudo-element, a little.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with JQuery code then I can suggest following solution. You can `split` the html and `append` the `li` in the given `class`. Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/1vowc2ju/#&togetherjs=54VgyoVmzq):

```js
var ul=$('<ul>');
var html = $('.magicbullets').html().split('\n');
$.each(html,function(index,element){
if(element !="")
{
var li = $('<li>',{text : element});
ul.append(li);
}
});
$('.magicbullets').empty().html(ul);
```

```css
.magicbullets {
     white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="magicbullets">
Nice
awesome
cool
</div>
```

Comment: As I said: No ClientCode(JS)

Answer (score -5):

CSS:

```
bullet:before {
    content: "•";
    padding-right: 8px;
    color: blue;}
```

Hope it helps, using it like :

```
<bullet>nice</bullet><br>
<bullet>awesome</bullet><br>
<bullet>cool</bullet><br>
```

Should output :

- nice
- awesome
- cool

Comment: _"but I cannot modify the content itself"_

Comment: If the user is able to modify the markup, then the correct solution is to just add a `<ul>` and `<li>`s, not to invent a `<bullet>` tag.