# How to adding bullet before every row in the class only uses css

Tags: html, css

How to add bullet before each line when only manipulated on css. I must not edit the HTML to use `<ul> <li>` . This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="info">
Thông tin ứng dụng<br />
Phiên bản<br />
Dung lượng <br />
Ngày cập nhật<br />
Tìm hiểu thêm</div>
```

Please help me to solve it. Thank you all.

Comment: Is this a school assignment or coding challenge? What is preventing you from adding proper markup? I feel like any solution here would be hacky at best.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bullet-like list without list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188560/bullet-like-list-without-list)