# Hide non-tagged content with only css

Tags: css

I have come across the following problem: i wish to hide the "..." that are displayed within the `.footer` div after the link, as shown in the picture below.

**Only caveat:** I can only use CSS to do so.

[image: Dev Tools Screenshot]

Can anybody tell me how to achieve this please?

Comment: To be helped you should post your full html (into eventually a snippet) ,that shows the issue, not a useless image :)    .... if it is only about text, then font-size should do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `visibility:hidden` in `div` parent and `visibility: visible` in child `a`

```css
div {
  visibility: hidden
}
div a {
  visibility: visible
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <a href="#">All courses</a>
  ...
</div>
```

other approach is `font-size:0`

```css
div {
  font-size: 0
}
div a {
  font-size: initial
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <a href="#">All courses</a>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From my comment about the use of `font-size`:

```css
div {
  font-size: 0;
  border:solid;
}
div * {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin:0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#">link to see</a> "text to hide "<a href="#">link to see</a>
  <p>some more text here</p>
   "Also some text to hide "
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of hiding content within a div is using this although it will also hide everything else contained within the div. If this is not what you hope to achieve please elaborate more.

```
    .footer {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    <div class="footer">
    "..."
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wraper p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1.3em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wraper">
  <a href="#">All courses</a>
  <p>&nbsp;Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `:not` and a color property

```
.footer:not(a){
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Edit: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbt62s6e/)

Comment: i do not think it will work, text to hide is not encapsulate in a tag ....

Comment: You can use a color property. See my jsFiddle