# How to target direct text and not text within tags?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way to only target the direct text within a `<h1>`-Tag?

Here is an example on what I want to do:

```
<h1>I want to select this text with a css selector <small>but not this text</small></h1>
```

This does not seem to work:

```
h1:not(small)
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: No, but you can target the one in `<small>` and unset  what you just set for `<h1>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `h1:not(small)`

Your selector `h1:not(small)` doesn't work because it says this:

> *Target all `h1` elements that are not `small` elements.*

It's that same as using the `h1` selector by itself.

---

### `h1 :not(small)`

You would have been closer with `h1 :not(small)`, which says:

> *Target all descendants of an `h1` except `small` elements.*

Boom! Exactly what you want.

Except that text contained directly inside an element (i.e, text with no tags around it) becomes an **anonymous element**. And [anonymous elements are not selectable by CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43027851/3597276).

```css
h1 :not(small) {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<h1>This text is contained directly inside the container. It is not selectable by CSS. It is an anonymous element. <small>This text is inside a small element</small></h1>

<hr>

<h1><span>This text is contained in a span. It is selectable by CSS</span> <small>This text is inside a small element</small></h1>
```

---

### CSS Parent Selector

For the `small` element to be excluded it would have to identify itself as a child of the `h1`.

But there is [no parent selector in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/3597276).

---

### Solution: Two selectors

You need two selectors to make this work:

- The first sets the style on the parent.
- The second overrides the first on the child.

```css
h1 {
  color: orange;
}

h1 > small {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>I want to select this text with a css selector <small>but not this text</small></h1>
```

---

### More Information

- [Targeting text nodes with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38449462/3597276)
- [Is it possible to style anonymous flex items explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43027851/3597276)
- [Is it possible to select elements not preceded by text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46920430/3597276)

Comment: thanks for your specific answer. I was able to work with: h1 :not(small)

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest it gets to retaining the style without any css that has been implemented by the parent div. This feature hasn't been fully integrated in all browsers, but it should work for some. Hope, it helps.

Browser support -

[image]

What's being done here?

The small tag is retaining its original CSS without being affected by the other styles. You can apply this on any of the child elements whose style you want to preserve.

```css
small {
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  }
}
h1 {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>I want to select this tex with a css selector <small>but not this text</small></h1>
```

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question asked. This does one thing: selecting any child of `h1` that is not a `h1` itself. It doesn't exclude the `span` from adopting its parents styles...

Comment: Updated, check it again if it satisfies your query now. @agrm

Comment: Just something to keep in mind, this answer doesn't work on [a few browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all). (as of the time of this comment)

Answer (score 0):

Apply styles to `h1` however you want, then, revert those changes in `small`, for example, if you only want to change the color you would use this code;

```css
h1 { color: red; }
h1 small { color: initial; }
```

Or, if you have multiple style changes;

```css
h1 {
    color: red;
    font-weight: italic;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 small {
    color: initial;
    font-weight: initial;
    text-transform: initial;
}
```

Please note that the `initial` CSS value can be used on every browser, except for IE and Opera Mini. View [this page](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value) for more information