# How to select the text node/content using CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to select the content/text node of a tag using css selectors?

For example I have some content such `<div><p class="x">Hello world</p></div>`. How can I get/select the text node ("hello world") using CSS?

I know that I could get the `p` element using `.x` class selector and then use innerHTML with javascript but I would like to know if it's possible to get the exactly text node using CSS and just set the node data (which is basically text as the node is a text node). Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by get/select the text node?

Comment: You can't manipulate the content of an element with CSS unless it is a `:before` or `:after` pseudo element.

Comment: @amflare I don't want to manipulate it with CSS. I just want to get it with querySelector

Comment: I'm even less clear now. `querySelector ` is JavaScript, not CSS

Comment: @mike but in your question you are saying _**I would like to know if it's possible to get the exactly text node using CSS**_

Comment: @mike, okay, then slap an ID on it and use `#id`

Comment: @j08691 but what goes inside querySelector(``) is a CSS, right?

Comment: [Yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: @amflare that would give me the "p" node. I need to get the underlaying  node which is a text node. (i.e. "hello world")

Comment: You want to do something to the text that ignores the padding, border, and margin?

Comment: `document.querySelector('.x').textContent`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

However, if you're trying to figure out how to select the text node with `querySelector`, do what @j08691 suggested:

```
document.querySelector('.x').textContent
```

That or

```
document.querySelector('.x').firstChild.nodeValue
```

should work.