# Make html comments visible using css

Tags: html, css, markdown

**Is there a way to make html comments visible in rendered html using css?**

This won't work, but something to this effect:

`htmlcomments {display: block;}`

Would turn:

```
<p>Hi</p>

<!-- howdy -->

<p>There</p>
```

Into this:

```
Hi

Howdy

There
```

Use case: I'm making markdown documents with inline comments and I'd like to view them with their formatting and also show the comments in the document.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You will have to read the nodes (html comments are nodes of the parent element) then create an element containing the node.TextContent

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand that. Would that be something I'd do with a script? I'm working with markdown files (with html comments) on my local machine, is this solution possible this case?

Comment: Most certainly not possible with CSS (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes). Poul was talking about JavaScript.