# html/css: underline on hover each word of a div, without wrapping

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have the following div:

```
<div>aaa, bbb- ccc. eee fff</div>
```

I was wondering if there is a css trick/property/function to apply a `text-decoration: underline` to the `div` on hover and have the underline appear only in the word where the cursor is? I know I can do it by wrapping each word in a span, but that doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: I don't see any efficiency problem by wrapping the word in a `span`. Doing some CSS tricks (granted it existed for your case) it will be probably causing some issue in some browser version. I'd say play safe here. Nothing wrong with using a span tag for styling

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688758/5385381

Answer (score -1):

You can split with the space and add span for each and every word. Then u can write text decoration to the span like below:

```
div:hover span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: he said: *I know I can do it by wrapping each word in a span,*