# CSS Selector: Style element left or right from text

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a button which contains an icon, and the possibility to add a text. This text is optional and can be on the left- or on the right-handside. Depending on the position, the margin of the icon differs.

That means:

- if the icon is on the **left**-handside, it should have a **margin-left** of e.g. 5px
- if it's on the **right**-handside, **margin-right** should be e.g. 10px
- if there is no text at all, the icons margin should be e.g. 2px

Is there any way to style the icon **without** adding additional css (helper) classes like `is-right` and **without** changing the markup? Maybe there is some pseudo selector, which could help here?

```
<button>
    <span class="icon editIcon"></span>
    Edit
</button>

<button>
    Edit
    <span class="icon editIcon"></span>
</button>

<button>
    <span class="icon editIcon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Does your text absolutely needs to be nude in here? If it was wrapped in an Element that would make things way easier.

Comment: yeah, I know...Then I could select it. But in this case I can't wrap the text element. In the worst case, I'll add helper classes, but I would like to avoid them

Comment: I personally don't see any selector that could let you know about that... All pseudo-classes like :nth-... are only taking Elements into account. TextNodes are second class citizen for CSS. But maybe someone knows a way.

Comment: alright, thanks anyways!

Comment: And actually there [is something making its way](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3216) (currently only implemented by Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/t1mzL4xg/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes)

Comment: @Kaiido That's exactly I was looking for. But also for other browsers. Looks like I have to introduce additional classes

Comment: And looking at the link I posted earlier it sounds like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-trim should be the solution for your margin issue. (AFK rn and couldn't test its behavior though) but that's very new

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `word-spacing` if you make the icon `inline-block`

```css
button {
  border:1px solid;
  word-spacing:10px;
}

.icon {
  display:inline-block;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<button>
    <span class="icon editIcon"></span>
    Edit
</button>

<button>
    Edit
    <span class="icon editIcon"></span>
</button>

<button>
    <span class="icon editIcon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: You haven't taken into account `Depending on the position, the margin of the icon differs.`

Comment: @Daut this is what I actually did, the margin differ when the icon is on the left or the right ... so we have a margin-left if the icon is on the right and a margin-right if on the left making the space between icon and text always the same. This is the question if I understand it well

Comment: I cannot see it, sorry, could you explain it :D

Comment: @Daut you don't see the space between the icon and text? this is the margin needed (if of course I understand the question well). he want to apply a margin depending on the position but I found another way to do it using word-spacing. So I no more need to know the position

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, thats already going in the right direction. But to be more specific, if the icon is on the left side, the icon should have a left-margin of 5px, and if it's on the right side, the right-margin is 10px. I'll update the description

Comment: @thn also avoid saying *I want to select text* .. you will get closed with irrelevant duplicate, describe your requirement without describing how you think it should be done. We don't need to select the text or the icon