# Select text node in a single element with multiple text nodes

Tags: html, css

I am trying to select a single text node from an element with multiple text nodes.

I have tried so far without success:

`#specifications-2 > div.tab-specifications > div[1]`

`#specifications-2 > div.tab-specifications > div:nth-child(1)`

[image: Element]

Comment: You can't do that for text nodes. You will need to wrap them inside an element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes)

Comment: So, in short you don't have a `<div>` but textnodes. What do you mean by saying "I want to select"? Select means what exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't modify the code, I just need to extract data from a website.

Comment: I am creating a web crawler and I need to select those text nodes but each one separately

Comment: That question was referring to a website where editing was possible

Comment: Fetch the page data. Target the element containing the text and than you could use RegExp to retrieve all the needed parts.

Comment: Can you help me with the regexp please?

Comment: @StylianosCharalambous sure. Create a jsFiddle.net with that specific DIV's contents

Comment: The contents of the div are not always the same though... This is for this specific element https://jsfiddle.net/cbernzkL/

Comment: @StylianosCharalambous https://regex101.com/r/LHcmdh/1 given a newline is used as separator.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately it doesn't work though. How can I split on the <br class>?

Comment: @StylianosCharalambous if you want you can get the element's `textContent`, than use `.split("\n")` to get the Array of lines, than you could simply split by the first occurrence of `:` and you'll get the desired Property : Value.

Comment: @StylianosCharalambous here's an example of the two ways: https://jsfiddle.net/eyb8qtr5/