# CSS: How to access immediate next node including :text elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<p class="message">
     Hi there
     <span class="emoji-native"></span>
     this is cool!
     <span class="emoji-native"></span>
     <span class="emoji-native"></span>
<p>
```

I want to add a `margin: 0 3px;` for all `.emoji-native` nodes and I also want to set `margin-left: 0px` for immediate next `.emoji-native` node.

This is the CSS code I have:

```css
.emoji-native {
      margin: 0 3px;
}
.emoji-native + .emoji-native {
      margin-left: 0px;
}
```

It works well when I have multiple emojis next to each other (exactly what I want), but, if I have text between emojis, it will also affect the last emoji, meaning the `+` operator does not count `:text` elements as nodes and just ignores them.

Is there a way to do this without wrapping the text contents into another `<span>` tag?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no way to reference text nodes in css, see this thread: [Is there a CSS selector for text nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes)

There is an open draft for the w3c, though i don't know if they'll implement it: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2208

Hope this answers your question. I guess the best you can do really is wrapping each text content in its own `<span>` tag.