# Detect two immediately adjacent links using only CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink, css-selectors, anchor

***TL;DR**: how to style links (or any HTML element, for that matter) that are next to each other, with no other content in between?*

Sometimes links can be placed next to each other, but [pointing](https://example.com) [to](https://google.com) [different](https://wikipedia.org) [places](https://stackoverflow.com) (← like this), which makes it hard if the site's style differentiates links merely by color. This is a pretty common practice. In fact, here's Wikipedia doing exactly that, in [the article about hyperlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink#Link_behavior_in_web_browsers):

[image]

Of course, the good practice of underlining links either permanently or on hover is sufficient to disambiguate the cases that are separated by whitespace, but there are cases where links are indeed immediately adjacent, [like](https://example.com)[this](https://google.com). This is less common, but I have come across it in the wild.

I am trying to define a user stylesheet to make these links immediately evident, and thought about using the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to do this, e.g.:

```css
a+a { border-left: 1px solid red; }
```

This indeed is able to detect "glued" links like `<a href="1"/><a href="2"/>` (self-closing syntax used for conciseness) and whitespace-separated links like `<a href="1"/> <a href="2"/>`. However, it also captures links with text in between like `<a href="1"/> foobar <a href="2"/>`:

```css
a+a { border-left: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="1">one</a><a href="2">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="1">one</a> <a href="2">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="1">one</a> foobar <a href="2">two</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have searched around but it [seems to be impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5688712/266309) to differentiate the first and second cases above from the third, i.e. to **style adjacent links only when there's no text content between them**. Would there be any trick I'm missing that would allow such a functionality?

Comment: is adding a white space in the first case a solution?

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, because I'm trying to use CSS (via user style sheets) to adjust sites not authored by me.

Comment: I meant adding white space **using CSS** not inside the html

Comment: Oh, I see. But what I'm looking for is something that stands out to indicate this as a problem, not just to split out the links visibly. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By no means a full, general solution, but put here in case it helps towards something better.

In the first case scenario, and including no background-color being set, you can put a thin line before and after each anchor element.

Where they overlap they can be made black by mix-blend-mode: difference.

Otherwise they are not seen as they are white.

```css
a::after,
a::before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="1">one</a><a href="2">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="1">one</a> <a href="2">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="1">one</a> foobar <a href="2">two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the idea :) I'm marking this as the accepted answer since I'm pretty sure there's no standards-based, semantically clean way to accomplish this via CSS alone. Cheers!