# Fix Flex Box Size Regardless of it's innerText

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I fix div's size? (I mean *.long* `div` on this codes)

Actually div's size is fixed. but, div's inner text is changing its width.

So, Position of Floating Point of my content is Changing.

I think cause of this problem is `flex-end`.

than, What is Best way of this problem with notating content on end of `div`?

[image]

```css
.parent{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
}

.long{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}

.short{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="long">
       {dynamicNumberNotate}
    </div>
    <div class="short">
        foo
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The text is a text node so it can't be styled. You'll have to wrap it in another element to fix its width. To fix your decimal place you'll have to put the whole number in the one element and the numbers after the decimal place in an adjacent one. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes

Comment: @Adam What do you mean, 'it's a text node'? It's a div. It *can* be styled.

Comment: It can't unfortunately. A text node in the DOM is just that, text. If you want to style it you'll have to wrap it in a div or a span. I'll fire up an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to ensure your decimal point doesn't move as the text moves, you have to split your div in to two sub elements. Ensure the 2nd has enough width to cope with 2 characters. There's a really handy css unit called `ch` for this.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    const numString = (Math.random() * 3000).toFixed(2);
    document.querySelector('.long').textContent = numString.split('.')[0] + ".";
    document.querySelector('.short').textContent = numString.split('.')[1];
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.long {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

.short {
  width: 2ch;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="long"></div>
  <div class="short"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div `.long` has a width of 80% of its parent, which is not a fixed width. There are three possible solutions:

- Give it a fixed width (e.g. 400px)
- Use the `word-break` css property to break the number apart when it's too long
- Make sure that there's enough space for the number to fit.

Additionally, the `display` property is a bit tricky and can have unexpected effects. Perhaps you can achieve a better result changing something in conjuction with a different display value for the child divs.