# CSS selector for not the first content in parent

Tags: css

I have HTML containing `<p>` elements which, in addition to text and phrase-level markup like `<i>` elements, sometimes contain `<button>` elements.  (The HTML is documentation of a user interface, so this mixed content seems to make sense.)  Examples:

```html
<p>A <i>really</i> great description. <button>Foo</button></p>
<p><a href="/">Link</a>. <button>Bar</button></p>
<p>Description. <button>Baz</button></p>
<p><button>Quux</button></p>
```

I want to increase the spacing around the buttons, which is most obviously done with the `margin-left` and `margin-right` CSS properties.  *However*, when the paragraph starts with a button, as the fourth paragraph above does, I want it to remain flush with the page margin.

I thought I had this working with this CSS:

```css
* + button { margin-left: 0.5rem; }
```

... but it turned out this was only working because most paragraphs lots of italics and hyperlinks, so there's usually some other element in the text before the `<button>` element, as in the first two `<p>` elements in my example above.  Unfortunately, in the third `<p>`, the `* + button` selector does not match; nor does `button:not(:first-child)`.  Both fail because the `<button>` element *is* the first child element, just not the first content.  In a more XPath-like syntax it would be `*|text() + button`.  Is there some way of achieving this in CSS?

Alternatively, is there some way of getting a space that somehow collapses into the paragraph margin, a bit like table borders under `border-collapse: collapse`, or that only applies between items, like the `gap` property in flexboxes, grid and multi-column layout?

I'm keen to avoid solutions that involve changing the HTML, e.g. by adding a spurious `<span>` to the text before the button, or by adding a class depending on whether the paragraph starts with the button.  (This is partly because the HTML is auto-generated by a process out of my control.)

The best I've achieved so far is the following, which works for the four examples above:

```css
p { margin-left: -0.5rem; }
p::first-letter { margin-left: 0.5rem; }
button { margin-left: 0.5rem; }
```

However this makes it difficult to apply any other styling to paragraphs, particularly borders or backgrounds which are broken by the fictitious margin.  It also strikes me as quite fragile, as it relies on the `::first-letter` pseudo-element not matching when the `<p>` starts with a block element like `<button>`, but matching when the first letter is within a phrase-level element.

Is there a better solution using just CSS?

Comment: I was thinking of `button:not(:first-child) {margin-left: 2em;}`, but that doesn't cover where there's just text content before the `button`. :sadface:

Comment: I believe since there is no direct way to target **text-content** of `<p>` in css. Due to that it would be difficult to achieve this. So whichever selector you apply, it will be applied to both the buttons of 3rd and 4th paragraphs. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5688758/19090048 . I know you don't want to add spurious `<span>` or `<div>` but unfortunately you have to do it or you need to use javascript or jquery.

Comment: Are you able to run a script that looks for the nodes inside the paragraph elements and checks if one if a text node? If so, you could potentially take it and wrap it in a span tag.

Comment: @GoodJuJu – yes, post-processing the HTML to add something that CSS can test is probably the right answer. It's more work that a client-side Javascript solution, but it feels better.  It is disappointing that either is necessary, though.  Is anyone aware of any proposed new features of CSS that will make this possible in the future?  I can't see anything for selecting text nodes in the current [CSS Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/) working draft.

Comment: It seems that this will be fixed in [CSS Box Model 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-4/) which allows you to write `p { margin-trim: inline; }`.  This removes the left margin on the first child node and the right margin on the last child node.  Unfortunately only Safari supports this as of late 2023.