How to style a pure text with no element?
I would like to style the 'TextWithNoStyle', but as it has no element, how can this be possible?
<div class=“MyClass”>
  <a href=“#Something”>Some Text</a>
  TextWithNoStyle
</div>

The style needs to affect only the 'TextWithNoStyle' text.

Depends what kind of style you want to apply.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688712/is-there-a-css-selector-for-text-nodes

This question is similar to: How to select a text node with CSS. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Here's a possible way: Do the styling with a css rule for MyClass, then create another rule for .MyClass > a where you set the previously styled parameters to initial (i.e. their default value):


.MyClass {
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.MyClass > a {
  font-size: initial;
  font-weight: initial;
}
<div class="MyClass">
  <a href="#Something">some link</a>
  TextWithNoStyle
</div>



Note: a has its own color definition by default, so you don't have to / shouldn't reset it using initial.

You could add some default styles to MyClass then override them into the a tag or others.
Also you have css pseudo elements selectors like :first-line or :first-letter
I leave a link that answers this
Styling Text without HTML Tag?

Something like this?


.MyClass {
  font: normal normal 16px/24px sans-serif;
  color: #F33;
}
<div class="MyClass">
  <a href="#Something"></a>
  TextWithNoStyle
</div>



